# Configure iOS keyboard to show shortcuts on top

Tags: ios

I am trying to replicate the functionality I saw in an app, where the Keyboard has shortcut buttons for '+', '-', '/' etc. on top of the keyboard.

I could not find any built in way to do this. Does this look like a custom UIView made visible when the keyboard appears?

[image]

Comment: check inputAccessoryView

Comment: create a `UIToolBar` with `UIBarButtonItem` , set the `UIToolBar` as `inputAccessoryView` for your `UITextField`

Comment: @ShebinKoshy Actually the UIToolBar part was not necessary. Any UIView, as long as it can fit, will do.

Comment: @reddragon Yes,  u can do with UIView also..